# Simulate map click on cesium entities

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm looking for a way to simulate mouse click on entity on cesium map, for automation tests using puppeteer or selenium..
or a way to convert cartesian2 or cartesian3 to a pixel xy position so I can click on the screen xy

Answer (score 1):

Yes I've done it on a project

```
const scene = new Cesium.Viewer().scene;
const worldPos = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude, height);
const windowPosition = Cesium.SceneTransforms.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates(scene, worldPos);
```